# how to send the xml parsing image data to ImageView.image

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml

I am working on parsing, I got the image data form the **XML** like [Link](http://www.cinejosh.com/telugu/newsimg/auto%20jony-chiran-1432900101-1.jpg)
then i sent this to detail view controller by using shared delegate.

```
AppDelegate *sharedDelegate=(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
imageview.image=[UIImage imageNamed:sharedDelegate.imagObj];
```

I got data in `sharedDelegate.image` but `Imageview.image` got only the `null` value.

Please help me.

Comment: If imagObj is UIImage then try imageview.image =sharedDelegate.imagObj . Check whether you are properly getting image data and saving it on imagObj.

Comment: kk ImageObj is the string,then what can i do?

Comment: where are you storing the image data ?

Comment: i am storing the data in array

Comment: i got from the xml and get into the array

Comment: in did selectrow at indexpath method i get into string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting a string, then use this code :

```
AppDelegate *sharedDelegate=(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",sharedDelegate.imagObj]]];
imageview.image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData]];
```

Comment: Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'UIImage *' from 'UIImageView *'

Comment: @juvvamahesh imageview.image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData]]; We are assigning UIImage to UIImage only...Check again your code.

Comment: the above warning shows when i use the only imageview i got the nil value in Imageview the result is frame = (0 0; 0 0); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9a8b767960>>

Comment: Have u created the imageview programatically or you have put it in xib? If programatically, you need to alloc it before use : For example , UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40,40,100,100)]

Comment: imageview.image=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];  when i write this i got frame = (20 67; 280 230); autoresize = BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fb27b75c7f0>>

Comment: @juvvamahesh So can you view the image now?

Comment: imageview.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sharedDelegate.imagObj]]];
i wrote this code I got the few images not all why

Comment: @juvvamahesh You need to check the image format. If all images are png and jpg, then it will load, but to load any other format, you need to write extra code. Pls mark the answer correct and upvote it if it helped you :P